# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: mode

Tags: iis-8

When I click the application pools on iis8,it threw the exception like title.I have reinstalled iis8，but it was no use.

Comment: What did you change recently?

Comment: I have only added/removed websites or apppools.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1207403.aspx?Restore+IIS+8+original+Default+Settings) website.

Comment: Thank you.I have read that post.And finally,I reinstall the IIS